# Change size of image picked from image gallery

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, image-manipulation

I want to change the size of an image selected from the photo gallery. Is it possible? I'm getting an image sized (320, 290) and I want to change the image size to (480, 320).

Comment: That will warp the image considerably. Are you sure you want to change the aspect ratio so drastically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to change the actual image, but only how it appears, then you can plunk the image as-is in a UIImageView and then make that view any size you like. It won't look great, especially if you are changing the aspect ratio, but it does the job.